# javascript remove function at runtime to avoid "multicall"

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, accordion

I've a javascript/jquery function:

```
function deleteRecordByClick(){
    $('.deleteRecord').click(function(){
        alert("deleting record");
        var confirmMsg = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete record?');    
        if(confirmMsg){  
            alert(idRecordToDelete);  // fires the correct id to delete
            ajaxDeleteRecord(idRecordToDelete); //my own ajax working properly      
        }               
    });
}
```

Which removes records from an accordion set. Each accordion is created dinamically and has a button with ".deleteRecord" class. Now the function is called properly but if i add N records, when i click on a random accordion, function is called N times even if obviously the delete on database fires only the first time and correctly, but i receive N confirm messages. I call the function when the record is created:

```
function addNewAccordion(){
   //.... my code to add accordion with
   // <h3 ... class="deleteRecord">
   deleteRecordByClick(); //here I call the function
}
```

Is there a method to destroy the function and recreate it or something better to resolve my issue? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you run the function each time you create an accordion, it will add another event handler to each of the previously created accordions.

You can first create all accordions and then call the function once, or you can send a reference to the specific accordion element into the function for each call:

```
deleteRecordByClick(accordion);
```

In the function you would use the reference to limit your search within that accordion:

```
function deleteRecordByClick(accordion){
  $('.deleteRecord', accordion).click(function(){
  ...
}
```

Comment: `As you run the function each time you create an accordion` this wasn't in his question, but well guessed

Comment: I thought about this as well, but are you sure that calling `click` does not overwrite any previously defined events? I can't find anything related to this in the [jQuery reference](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/click)

Comment: @Asad just have a look at the `addNewAccordion`.

Comment: Also, the docs say it binds an event handler, which does not imply that previous handlers are unbound first.

Comment: @clentfort: "As of jQuery 1.4.2 duplicate event handlers can be bound to an element instead of being discarded." http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Comment: I can't create first all the accordions because they are created dinamically and I can delete them whenever I want

Comment: @Franky: Then use the second method, where you bind the events for a specific accordion.

Comment: Sorry I'm not a jquery expert, how can I define the var "accordion" ?
Simply $(this).closest('h3')  ??

Comment: @Franky: It would be some element containing the `h3` element. I don't know what your code looks for adding the accordion, but you would either have a reference to the accordion, or a reference to the element where you add it. (The second wouldn't work if you have several accordions in the same parent element, then it would have to be the accordion element itself.)

Answer (score 1):

You should use event delegation:

```
$(addedAccordion).on('click', '.deleterecord', function(){/*stuff to delete entry here */})
```

inside addNewAccordion, instead of adding a listener to each element in the accordion.

```
function addNewAccordion() {
    //.... my code to add accordion with
    // <h3 ... class="deleteRecord">
    // var addedAccordion = ... get a reference to the accordion
    $(addedAccordion).on('click','.deleterecord', function() {
        alert("deleting record");
        var confirmMsg = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete record?');
        if (confirmMsg) {
            alert(idRecordToDelete); // fires the correct id to delete
            ajaxDeleteRecord(idRecordToDelete); //my own ajax working properly      
        }
    });
}
```